# have a button outside the collection view to do what the collection view cell is supposed to do

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a collection view acting as image carousel when i press on the cell a pdf file will open, the code below will do that. what i wanna do is to have a button to press on it instead of pressing on the cell itself. but i dont know how to do that because of that line   `self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBook", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "showBook"
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as! showMo2lfatVC
            vc.book = self.arrayBooks[self.selectedIndexPath.row]    
        }
    }
```

This is my button function and this is what i have tried

```
@IBAction func openBook(_ sender: Any) {

     //   self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
       // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showImage", sender: self)
     //    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
```

Comment: You want action on button press and not on cell selection?

Comment: yes but i want the button to be outside the collection view and collection view cell. is it possible to do that?

Comment: How can you select both the cell and the button?

Comment: it's an image carousel, i dont want to select the cell i wanna select a button instead but i dont know how to access indexPath i have to use this line in the button function      self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

Comment: Which indexpath do you want to access on button tap?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check it out and let me know if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `**indexPathsForSelectedItems**` property of `UICollectionView` to get the `indexPaths` of all the `selected` `UICollectionViewCells`. The number of elements you get depends on whether `multiple selection` is allowed in `UICollectionView` or not.

**Example:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showBook"
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        if let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first //Here
        {
            vc.book = self.arrayBooks[selectedIndexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func openBook(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBook", sender: self)
}
```

No need to create any separate variable `selectedIndexPath` to keep the track of the selected cell. Just call `performSegue` on `button tap` and do the rest of the work in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`